# How to change the color of the circle according the the degree

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

How can I modify the **UV index** indicator to ensure consistency in the color gradient representation between the arc and the circle? The current design displays the UV index as an arc with a color gradient from green to red, but the `circle` remains ungraded.

Below is the SVG and accompanying code for an application that includes a UV index indicator. The circle within the indicator is moved based on the current UV index value, which is reflected in the color gradient of the arc:

```js
let uvIndex = 10;

      if (uvIndex >= 10) uvIndex = 10;

      const percentage = uvIndex / 10;
      const degrees = (uvIndex / 10) * 180 + 90;
      const x = 50 + 40 * Math.cos((degrees * Math.PI) / 180);
      const y = 50 + 40 * Math.sin((degrees * Math.PI) / 180);

      const line = document.querySelector("line");
      const circle = document.querySelector("circle");

      circle.setAttribute("cx", x);
      circle.setAttribute("cy", y);
```

```html
 <div style="height: 300px; width: 300px; margin: 100px">
      <svg
        viewBox="0 0 100 50"
        style="height: 80%; width: 50%; transform: rotate(90deg)"
      >
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="color-gradient">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#4CAF50" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#FFEB3B" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#F44336" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
          d="M 10 50 A 40 40 0 0 1 90 50"
          stroke-width="5"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          fill="none"
          stroke="url(#color-gradient)"
          transform="rotate(-90,50,50)"
        />
        <circle cx="50" cy="10" r="5" fill="#000" />
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Additionally, I am interested in learning how to create an **animation** that **transitions** the `circle` within the **UV index** indicator from its starting position to its corresponding position based on the current UV index value. Could you please provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I suggest using a color form that is more amenable to that type of transformation, like HSL or LCH (or [OKLCH](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/oklch-in-css-why-quit-rgb-hsl))

Comment: What color should the circle have in your example? Should it have the color corresponding to it's position on the arc? Red in your example?

Comment: it should have a color similar to the arc where it's positioned

Comment: Maybe use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-color-gradient

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, well actually someone answered the first part of the question, but he has removed it, and I do not know why. Now the issue that I have with the animation, is a little tricky since the trajectory is a curved line, and while moving the circles' color needs to change, plus it is in a SVG elemnts

Comment: (I have more SO points) I can still see the deleted answer, it did not calculate the gradient, only extracted one of the 3 gradient colors.

Comment: I understood the approach, and it did work actually work, at first look at your suggestion (https://github.com/Adrinlol/javascript-color-gradient) I think this a neat way to make the gradient and set some colors in between as well. But the issue now is with the transition as I told you in the last comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using https://github.com/Adrinlol/javascript-color-gradient you can calc the gradients
between the 3 stop-colors.

Then a *native* JavaScript Web Component (JSWC) `<svg-uv-index>` can update all:
(added a slider for demo purposes)

[image]

*(needs some tweaking to get what you want)*

```html
<script src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/color-gradient.js"></script>

<svg-uv-index value=10 ></svg-uv-index>
<svg-uv-index value=50 ></svg-uv-index>
<svg-uv-index value=75 ></svg-uv-index>
<svg-uv-index value=100 ></svg-uv-index>

<script>
customElements.define("svg-uv-index", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let speed = 0.5; // set to 0.0001 for instant display!
    let arc = "M20,60a35,35 0 1,1 60,0";
    this.gradients = new Gradient()
          .setColorGradient("#4CAF50", "#FFEB3B", "#F44336")
          .setMidpoint(101)
          .getColors();
    this.innerHTML = 
    `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="0"`+ // delete 2 lines
    `       oninput="this.parentNode.percent=this.value" /><br>`+ // just for demo
    `<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <linearGradient id="color-gradient">
        <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="${this.gradients[0]}"/>
        <stop offset="50%"  stop-color="${this.gradients[50]}"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="${this.gradients[100]}"/>
      </linearGradient>    
       <path d="${arc}" stroke="grey" stroke-width="6" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
       <path id="P" d="${arc}" stroke="url(#color-gradient)" stroke-width="8" 
             pathLength="100" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="75 35"/>
       <circle stroke="grey" cx="0" cy="0" fill="#fff" r="4" stroke-width="6">
         <animateMotion dur="${speed}s" path="${arc}" keyPoints="0;0.75" 
                        fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"/>
       </circle>
       <text x="50%" y="40%" text-anchor="middle">XXX</text>
     </svg>`;
    this.style.display = 'inline-block';
    this.percent = this.getAttribute("value") || "50";
  }
  set percent(val = 0) {
    this.setAttribute("value", val);
    let dash = val + " " + (105 - val);
    let gradientIdx = ~~(val/1);
    this.querySelector("circle").setAttribute("stroke",this.gradients[gradientIdx]);
    this.querySelector("animateMotion").setAttribute('keyPoints', '0;'+val/100);
    this.querySelector("#P").setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', dash);
    this.querySelector("text").innerHTML = val + `%`;
    this.querySelector("animateMotion").beginElement();
    this.querySelector("input").value = val;
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I needed, and I can even customize the speed of the animation as well