# animation motion happens instantly

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have made a custom **humidity indicator component** that consists of a vertical `rectangle` with a central `circle`. The purpose of this component is to visually represent the percentage of humidity. However, I encountered a problem where the `animation` for both the **color change** and the **movement** of the circle occurs instantly, without any smooth `transition`.

Here is the code responsible for declaring and setting the percentage of the humidity indicator element:

```
customElements.define(
    "svg-humidity-percentage",
    class extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
            let speed = 1.5;
            this.gradients = new Gradient()
                .setColorGradient("#4CAF50", "#FFEB3B", "#F44336")
                .setMidpoint(101)
                .getColors();
            this.style.display = "inline-block";
            this.style.height = "80%";
            this.percent = this.getAttribute("value")|| "0";

            this.innerHTML =
                `<svg width="50" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 200">
                   <rect id="rectangle" x="20" y="20" width="20" height="160" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#ccc" />
                   <circle id="circle" cx="30" cy="170" r="10" fill="#ff0000">
                        <animateMotion dur="${speed}s" path="M20 20 H40 V180 H20 Z" keyPoints="0;1" fill="freeze" calcMode="linear" />
                   </circle>
                </svg>`;
        }

        set percent(val) {
            document.querySelector('.weather-card').addEventListener('animationend', () => {
                let gradientIdx = ~~(val / 1);
                this.setAttribute("value", val);
                this.querySelector("circle").setAttribute("cy", "30"); // y(rect) + r(circle)
                this.querySelector("circle").setAttribute("fill", this.gradients[gradientIdx]);

                this.querySelector("animateMotion").setAttribute("keyPoints", "0;" + val);
                this.querySelector("animateMotion").beginElement();
            });
        }
    }
);
```

So far I am not setting the real value of the humidity I just set it to the minimum value which in this case `30` (the **CY** of the `rectangle` + the **radius** of `circle`), and since SVG is a [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions) where its starting points are from the top-left, it seems that it's going upside-down.

I am seeking an `animation` like the one of the `arc` provided **GIF**, which is from the solution provided in response to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081842/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-circle-according-the-the-degree?noredirect=1#comment134182540_76081842).

```js
customElements.define(
    "svg-humidity-percentage",
    class extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
            let speed = 1.5;
            this.gradients = new Gradient()
                .setColorGradient("#4CAF50", "#FFEB3B", "#F44336")
                .setMidpoint(101)
                .getColors();
            this.style.display = "inline-block";
            this.style.height = "80%";
            this.percent = this.getAttribute("value")|| "0";

            this.innerHTML =
                `<svg width="50" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 200">
                   <rect id="rectangle" x="20" y="20" width="20" height="160" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#ccc" />
                   <circle id="circle" cx="30" cy="170" r="10" fill="#ff0000">
                        <animateMotion dur="${speed}s" path="M20 20 H40 V180 H20 Z" keyPoints="0;1" fill="freeze" calcMode="linear" />
                   </circle>
                </svg>`;
        }

        set percent(val) {
            document.querySelector('.weather-card').addEventListener('animationend', () => {
                let gradientIdx = ~~(val / 1);
                this.setAttribute("value", val);
                this.querySelector("circle").setAttribute("cy", "30"); // y(rect) + r(circle)
                this.querySelector("circle").setAttribute("fill", this.gradients[gradientIdx]);

                this.querySelector("animateMotion").setAttribute("keyPoints", "0;" + val);
                this.querySelector("animateMotion").beginElement();
            });
        }
    }
);
```

```css
.weather-card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    width: 30%;
    height: 222px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    margin: 19px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    animation-name: card-animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.weather-card span.weather-card-title {
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #B6B6B6;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex: 0 0 10%;
}

.weather-card div.weather-card-information {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

div.humidity, div.wind, div.real-temperature-data, div.visibility, div.real-temperature-shade {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.humidity-data, .wind-data {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.humidity-data, .humidity-indicator {
    width: 50%;
}

.humidity-data-percentage, .humidity-data-description {
    height: 50%;
}

@keyframes card-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateY(50px);
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/color-gradient.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="weather-card">
        <span class="weather-card-title">Humidity</span>

        <div class="weather-card-information">
            <div class="humidity">
                <div class="humidity-data">
                    <div class="humidity-data-percentage">60</div>
                    <div class="humidity-data-description">Niiiice</div>
                </div>

                <div class="humidity-indicator">
                    <svg-humidity-percentage value=60></svg-humidity-percentage>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please use the [<>] button in the StackOverflow editor to convert the code in your post to a [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: **Check your browsers F12 console.** You have multiple issues mentioned there. Percentage value needs to be between 0 and 1. You are now setting ``60``. You haven't included the color-gradient library, so ``this.gradients`` is not set to the correct calculated gradients

Comment: Thank you, you are right I have set the keypoint to 60, and I have updated it to `setAttribute("keyPoints", "0;" + val / (100));`. I also checked that the color-gradient library is included indeed, the errors are gone now ,but still, the animation happens instantly

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I am not that expert with SVG animations, I have indicated that I want to make an animation like the previous question, the position of the circle was updated as well as the color of the circle. I checked the code over and over again, but I could not understand the issue. In my opinion, this place is for learning and helping each other and I think it is a question-and-answer format.

Comment: Your `<animateMotion>`  element also needs a `keyTimes="0;1"  attribute value (just stick to the original component code).  Otherwise the circle won't be aligned to the motion path. Besides, your motion path is a closed rectangular shape – you need a single line from bottom to top like `d="M30 170 v-150"` . The circle `cx`  and `cy` values should be 0 - otherwise it won't be aligned correctly to the motion path. See this static [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/wvYVPBm)